# Escape '@' in config folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to escape @ symbol in my config file so i can call it in my blade file. it is possible ?

In my config file

```
<?php
   return [
     'list' => ' 
            @if ($errors->has(\'image\'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first(\'image\') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif
        '
   ];
```

In my blade

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ config ('myFile.list') }}
</div>
```

Output:

```
                @if ($errors->has(\'image\'))
                <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first(\'image\') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your config file has invalid syntax, obviously.

Comment: sorry my bad, i already updated my post,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the files inside `config` folder are to store various configuration variables. such as database connectivity, email client connection etc... not to store blade snippets. and `@if, @else, @foreach` etc... should only be used in blade files. not in config files. to include a blade file in another blade file, you can simply use `@include` directive

```
eg: @include('filename')
```

The file should be residing in the `/resources` folder and it could contain any valid blade/PHP syntax.

**So for your question**, You can escape @ symbols by using `\@if` as if its in a normal string and put it in a config variable. but not a good practice overall.

you should take a look at [blade templating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

Comment: Thank you for the response, what im trying to do is to make a dynamic content that has a validation , do you have any suggestion how can i add a content in blade template, using javascript/jquery?

Comment: you can directly put `<script>` tags in blade files, or you can import scripts also. usually the intividual js files goes into `/resources/assets/js` folder. then we should compile it using some compiler. take a look into `laravel elixir`